# Ayuda con proyecto para conectar Arduino y servidor web

Tags: html, python, web, arduino

Estoy intentado hacer un proyecto donde quiero mover unos servomotores desde una web y no consigo hacerlo. El servidor es una Raspberry Pi y quiero mover los servomotores con unos sliders. La cosa es que para que se muevan los servomotores tengo este código en el Arduino:

```
/*
   MOVER DOS SERVOS CON ARDUINO
   Este codigo recibe numeros enteros por serial
   y mueve dos servos.

   Escrito por Nano en beneficio de los seres humanos <img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.3/svg/1f609.svg">
   www.robologs.net
*/
#include<Servo.h>

//Creamos los objetos servo
Servo servo;
Servo servo2;

int enviado; //Aqui enviamos el numero completo
int num; //Numero del servo
int posicion; //Posicion del servo

void setup()
{
  //Inicializamos los Servos
  servo.attach(9);
  servo2.attach(10);

  //Inicializamos la comunicacion por Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available() >= 1)
  {
    /*
    1- Leer un numero entero por serial
    2- Calculamos su modulo por 10 (sera el numero del motor)
    3- Dividir el entero inicial por 10
    4- Lo que quede, sera la posicion del motor
    */
    enviado = Serial.parseInt();
    num = enviado%10;
    enviado = enviado/10;
    posicion = enviado;

    //Hora de mover los servos!
    if(num == 1)
    {
      servo.write(posicion);
    }
    else if(num == 2)
    {
      servo2.write(posicion);
    }
  }

}
```

Eso es lo que tengo en el Arduino. Como podéis ver es muy sencillo controlar los servos, solo tengo que poner `(grados)(numero del servo)`. Ej: Para mover a 90 grados el segundo servo debo enviar `902`.

Pues bueno, estoy haciendo una web donde quiero que un `form` envíe el número que tiene puesto el slider a un script en Python y dependiendo del slider el script en Python añada al final de los grados el número del servo.

Aquí mi web:

```
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#boton1').click(function(){

        var dataString = $('#form1').serialize();

        alert('Datos serializados: '+dataString);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cgi-bin/script.py",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<form id="form1" data-ajax="false">
<label for="slider-fill">Input slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-fill" id="slider-fill" value="90" min="0" max="180" data-highlight="true">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="boton1">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

En el `form` podéis ver que pone `data-ajax="false"` ya que si no me da error la página ya que hay un bug con el form y el `jquery mobile`.

Aquí mi script python:

```
import cgi, cgitb
import serial
cgitb.enable()

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
searchterm =  form.getvalue('form1')
ser.write(str(searchterm) + "1")
```

Edit: Ya he puesto el 1 para que pueda moverse el servo.

Lo que quiero es sacar a parte el `value` de cada slider (ahora solo tengo uno pero quiero poner más) para luego poder añadirle el número al final que necesito (en este caso sería el 1). Después enviar el `value`+`el_numero_del_servo` para que se mueva el servomotor y ya está.

Puede ser que tenga muchas cosas mal ya que soy novato. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho ya que es para un proyecto del instituto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Orizzon, ¿Cual exactamente el problema actual que tienes? ¿Que parte es la que no hace lo que debería?

Comment: @FJSevilla Creo que mi problema principal es que no se como enviar el form con la información del slider al archivo Python. Tengo que enviarlo de tal forma que luego en Python pueda conseguir la información de cada slider por separado.

Comment: Orizzon debes usar un json para enviar los datos que desees procesar en el script, algo como `data: {'form1':valor_de_tu _slider}`.

Comment: ¿Pero eso donde debo ponerlo? He visto que hay gente que en el script AJAX ponen que se envie en json.

Comment: Además, la web de por si tiene algunos fallos que tengo que ir solucionando. El más importante es que cuando pulso el boton el slider vuelve a su `value` original que en este caso es 90 y yo quiero que se quede donde lo he dejado. Otro es que el url cambia y pone el `value` del slider.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un php para ejecutar el código python. Es la manera mas rápida y con menos código. Aca te dejo un [ejemplo](http://optimizarsinmas.blogspot.com.co/2012/05/php-ejecutar-script-python-pasando.html), sin embargo, veo que los únicos 2 parámetros que quieres pasar son grados y números de servo.

También el formulario esta mal debería ser algo `<form method="post" action="" id="form1">`, ya que debe usar un método, y una acción(la pagina que lo redirige, en este caso la misma), luego puedes obtener estos valores con php y mandarlos al código python. Cuéntame como te va

Answer (score 0):

En vez de usar Raspberry Pi puedes utilizar el módulo node mcu esp8266, yo estoy trabajando con un proyecto el cual es sobre domotica, monté un servidor web en él para poder controlar servomotores, un relevador y luces, todo esto por medio del navegador web. Una ventaja es que puedes programar directamente el módulo con el ide de arduino, además que ya no usaras comandos AT. Aquí te dejo un [Ejemplo](http://www.esploradores.com/access-point-servidor-web-nodemcu/), espero sea de ayuda, saludos.